# Need help decrypting a Windows 7 system drive with Diskcryptor

Tags: windows, decryption

I've had my Windows 7 64-bit Professional system drive fully encrypted with Diskcryptor, and now I'm trying to unencrypt it so that I can install several new operating systems.  I used DiskCryptor to decrypt both C: and the boot partition by selecting those drives in the DC window and selecting Decrypt.  The decryption went smoothly, and I can access the data on the pc.

The problem is the bootloader.  When I boot the computer up, I am still greeted by "Enter password:" rather than the Windows animation.  The funny thing is that if I simply hit ENTER rather than type a password, then Windows boots normally.

I've tried running the boot repair utility on my repair disk, but it failed to changed anything.  It's not really a problem, as Windows still boots normally and I'll be ditching 7 soon anyway, but I would like to remove all remains of the encryption if possible.  Does anyone know how I can restore the normal Windows boot process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The boot loader from Diskcryptor was not removed. To do that, start Diskcryptor, Go to 'Tools' - 'config bootloader' and click 'Remove loader'.

Reboot and loader will be gone.